# how to position box when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

How do I position the green box so the bottom of the box is aligned to bottom of space available when scrolling past its height using jQuery.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>

.content { width: 400px; position: relative; height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; border: 1px solid gray; }
.left { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 200px; background: red; height: 400px; }
.right { position: absolute; right: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: green; }


$('.content').scroll(function(){
    //how to position green box so the bottom of the box
    //is aligned to bottom of space available
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/ryFGK/4/

Comment: are you trying to prevent it from going beyond the bottom when scrolling? Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: i always want it to be in view. The box could sometimes be longer than the viewport, so it should always be positioned at the bottom of the screen once it starts to fix its position.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ryFGK/5/

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>

$('.content').bind('scroll', function(e) {
    var content = $(this);
    var scrollTop = content.scrollTop();
    var green = $('.right');
    console.log('Top: ' + green.position().top + ', ScrollTop: ' + scrollTop);
    if (scrollTop > green.height()) {
        green.css({top: scrollTop + content.height() - green.height()});
    } else {
        green.css({top: 0});
    }
});
```

Comment: it should stick to the bottom of the viewport, as soon as there is space for it as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/ryFGK/18/

I basically set an initial css

```
bottom: 0
```

on the green box.

Checked the scroll top, if it is > than the height of the green box, then I snap it to the bottom and when scrolling back up, the else condition fires and snaps it back to the bottom.

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Please check